# Windows 11 booting causes weird (non-critical) grub errors

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

Probably starting with some update for Windows 11 1-2 month ago, my dual-boot setup has been showing some weird behavior (having worked flawlessly before that). After I boot Windows 11, starting up GRUB shows the following weird errors:

```
Failed to open \EFI\UBUNTU\... - Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image \EFI\UBUNTU\... - Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter, falling back to default
```

[image: GRUB errors]

It still functions and boots both systems as expected (the only notable difference, apart from the aforementioned errors, is usage of low-resolution (80x40?) text mode for GRUB instead of default high-resolution one).

The problem can be fixed by running `grub-install` in Ubuntu but it comes back after I boot Windows next time (booting Ubuntu doesn't cause this issue). This behavior has been observed with both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04. Having suspected EFI directory corruption, I checked `/boot/efi` during the issue and after the "fix" and it shows no changes, so it might be something else.

I'm curious if anyone else observed this and knows how to fix it.

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must.

Comment: There are updates in Windows that enable Fast Startup feature automaticly although you had it turned off. So check this after updating Windows.

Comment: Tried disabling the Fast Startup - no effect...